# sum all price of the table SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sum

how to sum the row of the price in my table
here's my code.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT sum(Price) * FROM reservations as A
    inner join service as B on A.Res_ser_ID = B.Ser_ID
    inner join personel as C on A.Res_per_ID = C.Per_ID
    where Res_cus_ID = '$userID' ");
```

Comment: Sample input and output would greatly help here.  Depending on what you are trying to sum, your query may already be correct.

Comment: Im trying to sum the price(column name) of the reservations(table name) to display the total price of all records in the form..

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to supported software such as `mysqli_`.  PHP's mysql_ API has been unsupported for many years.  Then you can use parameters -- a key to safe and effective use of SQL from applications.

I think something like this (not using parameters):

```
SELECT sum(s.Price) as sum_price
FROM reservations r JOIN
     service s 
     ON r.Res_ser_ID = s.Ser_ID
WHERE r.Res_cus_ID = '$userID';
```

This assumes that the price comes from the `service` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
"select sum(service.price) as sum_price from (reservations  inner join
 service  on reservation.Res_ser_D = service.Ser_ID inner join personnel
 on reservation.Res_per_ID = personnel.Per_ID ) where
 reservation.Res_cus_ID = '$userID'"
```

this shall work ,i have assumed that the price is in table service.